# How to fix sound control problems?

Tags: sound, volume-control

I'm having some issues with sound control.

I'm running ububtu 13.10 on HP Pavilion g6. For a while sound worked perfectly, but since skype started barring,I got too lots of sound issues.

The problem that I'm facing is that the whole system got itself a default volume intensity which I am not able to control anymore neither from buttons and system settings.

I know this question was similarly asked but, no one got the answer to get it fixed.

Thanks!

Comment: now I have no sound at all ...

Comment: well guys, problem kind of solved, I was thinking to use these tips  [link](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) but simply when I clicked on "speakers built in audio", the whole system "got to minimum" then sound started working and the controls too... wow,that's weird...